# How to install mono 4.8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: installation, mono, ubuntu-16.04

Ok, I feel like I should be able to figure this out based on the documentation provided by Mono, but nothing is working. Based on [this guide](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-ubuntu) and [this note](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/), I've tried running

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/snapshots/4.8.0" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
```

I've modifed that 2nd line a few times and or simply edited /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list, trying other similar things, butevery time I run the sudo apt-get update, I get:

```
user@NAS:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I need 4.8, as the app I need to use with mono does not work as well with 5.0. I currently have mono 4.2.1, but I believe it came pre-installed on my distro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure looks sound, one small issue is that the second step should be

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu wheezy/snapshots/4.8.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
```

Next step (after apt-get update) is installing the mono-devel 4.8.0 package and all its dependencies by version:

```
apt-get -f install \
 mono-devel=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-cecil-private-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-mcs=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-gac=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-xbuild=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-cil-dev=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-2.0-dev=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmonosgen-2.0-dev=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-accessibility4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-cairo4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-csharp4.0c-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-data-tds4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-db2-1.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-http4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-i18n4.0-all=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-ldap4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-management4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-messaging4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-oracle4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-parallel4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-peapi4.0a-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-posix4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-relaxng4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-security4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-simd4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-sqlite4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-core4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-design4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-json4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-management4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-net4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-security4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-mobile4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-regularexpressions4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-windows4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-workflow-activities4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-workflow-componentmodel4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-workflow-runtime4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-xml4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-tasklets4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libnunit-cil-dev=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2 \
 libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-peapi4.0a-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-relaxng4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-csharp-shell=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-4.0-gac=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-gac=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-runtime=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-i18n-mideast4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-i18n-other4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-i18n-rare4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 ca-certificates-mono=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 libmonosgen-2.0-1=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 "libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2" \
 "libnunit-core2.6.3-cil=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2" \
 "libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2" \
 "libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2" \
 "libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2" \
 "libnunit-util2.6.3-cil=2.6.3+dfsg-1~xamarin2" \
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-runtime-sgen=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 mono-runtime-common=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11 \
 monodoc-browser=4.2-0xamarin1 \
 monodoc-base=4.8.0.524-0xamarin11
```

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you add ppa with target version (as user8174722 said)

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu wheezy/snapshots/4.8.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
```

and you have not add any other version or main repo, you can install mono v4.8.0 with pure

```
apt install mono-devel
```

and you don't need to specify all this versions.

But be sure that you do not have other mono-project's repo in your `/etc/apt` directory. You can check it with

```
grep -d recurse -e 'mono-project' /etc/apt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

^^ password authentication -> yes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please improve your answer and tell us why you believe that is a better answer than the previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can found instruction to setup latest version of mono for ubuntu 16.04 and other distros/version on mono project site
www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

Ubuntu 16.04 (i386, amd64, armhf, arm64, ppc64el)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-
keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update

sudo apt install mono-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the various packages is to build it from source.

This can be handy as you can also change the install location and have multiple versions installed at the same time.

I've already explained how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76049418/16038645