# Install Mono-Complete 4.8 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I'm trying to install `Mono 4.8` in a `Docker` image but I am failing to download. Here is the dockerfile

```
  RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y curl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys     3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
  && echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list \
  && echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list \
  && echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libjpeg62-compat main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y clang \
  && apt-get install -y mono-complete=4.8.0.520-0xamarin3
```

It fails to install mono-compete with this error message

```
E: Version '4.8.0.520-0xamarin3' for 'mono-complete' was not found
```

I was wondering what should be the mono-complete 4.8 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pin the `version` to the `snapshots` directory:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu wheezy/snapshots/4.8.0.520 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
```

Get the required dependencies:

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
```

Add the repository keys:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys A6A19B38D3D831EF
```

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After modifying/update the caches, you can use `apt-cache policy {package}` to determine if the version you wish to install is available.

```
>apt-cache policy mono-complete
mono-complete:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.0.520-0xamarin3
  Version table:
     4.8.0.520-0xamarin3 500
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu wheezy/snapshots/4.8.0.520/main amd64 Packages
     4.6.2.7+dfsg-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 Packages
```

Now you can install `4.8.0.520-0xamarin3`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mono-complete=4.8.0.520-0xamarin3
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [SushiHangover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47323202/16038645https://) is to build it from source.

This can be handy as you can also change the install location and have multiple versions installed at the same time, here is a tutorial: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/

Note that while testing it I found a few problems that you have to fix and divert slightly from the tutorial:

- Make a folder with a name of your choice and download/create everything inside it, I simply called it `mono-4.8` with `~/mkdir mono-4.8` and moved inside the folder with `cd ~/mono-4.8`
- Install "libtool" with `sudo apt install libtool` (it seems to work also without this but it complains if you don't have it installed)
- Add the line `export TERM=xterm` to the file `mono-dev-env` (explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260701/16038645)
- When extracting the Tar Ball, instead of `tar zxf FILENAME` use `tar -xf FILENAME`
- Add the line `#include <sys/sysmacros.h>` in the beginning of `mono/io-layer/processes.c` (explained here: https://github.com/cydhaselton/mono-android/issues/1#issuecomment-501959957)
- Use `make -j $(($(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)-1))` instad of just `make` when compiling so you use all your cpu cores except one instead of just 1