# Can't downgrade mono

Tags: mono

I can't seem to find how to install the 4.0.5.1 version of mono for ubuntu 16.04.

i've tried changing it in sources.list.d but when I do mono --version, it's still the 4.2.1 version.

Keep in mind this is my first time using linux. I'm just trying to setup an AFK script for minecraft alts on my vps.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you wish to specifically install version 4.0.5.1 of the mono runtime?

Comment: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1263927-win-mac-linux-minecraft-console-client?page=98 (#1997) This is where the developper of the tool says to use a version between 4.0 and 4.2. I got told somewhere else that 4.0.5.1 was the best. I'm just following steps that have been provided.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question on [ubuntu.se]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Mono-Complete 4.8 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321441/install-mono-complete-4-8-on-ubuntu)